# Timer Not Repeating (Grand Central Dispatch)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

I'm trying to learn how to dispatch computations on a background thread and resultantly update the UI after. When I attempt this in an existing project with Google Maps, "background" followed by "main" is printed once. No more printing occurs, as if the timer does not repeat.

Further, when I create a blank application and add this code in, nothing prints at all.

```
let queue = dispatch_queue_create("myTimer", nil);
let timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer) {
    println("background")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { println("main") })
}

dispatch_resume(timer)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that something long-lived has a reference to both this queue and this timer. Without explicitly checking, my impression from your snippet here is that `timer` and `queue` will be released when this goes out of scope. The `dispatch_resume` may cause the first event to be queued up, which may cause `queue` and `timer` to live long enough to perform the first iteration, after which their retain counts go to zero and they get deallocated.

Try making sure they stick around for a while...

For instance, starting from the iOS Single View Application project template in Xcode, and with the following in `AppDelegate.swift`, the timer repeats just fine:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var queue: dispatch_queue_t?
    var timer: dispatch_source_t?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("myTimer", nil);
        timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
        dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC);

        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer) {
            println("background")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { println("main") })
        }

        dispatch_resume(timer)

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Gave it a try assigning values of timer and queue to my map view. Same result. Any tips as to how to go about this?

Comment: My only guess (from what you've said here) is that your map view is *also* going away at some point. I've added a trivial example where the queue and timer are owned by the AppDelegate and it works as expected.